# Converting image into bytes and dividing it into chunks

Tags: c#

I am trying to read a image file into bytes and divide those bytes into smaller chunks as shown in code below. Can someone guide me on whether this is the right & efficient approach to do it? Please help.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>> ReadByChunk(int chunkSize)
            {
                IEnumerable<char> result;
                int startByte = 0;
                do
                {
                    result = ReadBytes(startByte, chunkSize);
                    startByte += chunkSize;
                    yield return result;
                }
                while (result.Any());
            }
    
            public static IEnumerable<char> ReadBytes(int startByte, int byteToRead)
            {
                char[] result;
                byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\1.jpg");
                for (int i = startbyte; i <= b.length; i++)
                {
                    result = b;
                }
                return result;
            }            
            public static void Main()
            {
                const int chunkSize = 2048;
                foreach (IEnumerable<byte> bytes in ReadByChunk(chunkSize))
                {
                  //more code
                
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous problems with your code:

1. Every single call to `ReadBytes` reads the entire file into memory.
2. The `for` loop in `ReadBytes` doesn't actually chunk the result, it simply assigns `b` to `result`, meaning that the result form this method is always the entire file.
3. For some reason you're trying to use `char` for *binary data*. This is not a good idea because text encoding doesn't work correctly for binary data. Encoding an arbitrary series of bytes with, for example, UTF8, and reversing that won't get you the same byte values.
4. Because `ReadBytes` always returns the entire file, `while (result.Any())` will loop forever (unless the file is empty).

Here is a more correct way to do it:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<byte>> ReadByChunk(int chunkSize)
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenRead("filename")) // open the file as a stream
    {
        byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkSize]; // create a byte array equal to our chunkSize
        int bytesRead = 0;
        // when `Read` returns `0`, it means we've reached the end of the file
        // so loop while the number of bytes read is > 0
        while ((bytesRead = reader.Read(chunk, 0, chunkSize)) > 0)
        {
            // take the actual number of bytes read and return
            // this chunk as an array
            yield return chunk.Take(bytesRead).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```